# Why an syntax error when I made alias in the nested query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT customers.Name
FROM 
    (SELECT *
     FROM customers AS c
     INNER JOIN orders AS o
     ON c.Id=o.CustomerId) AS co
WHERE customers.Name NOT IN co; #Syntax error: co
```

19:21:06 Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'co' at line 7 0.000 sec

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check the manual for the right syntax as advised?

Comment: You cannot use an alias as operator to `IN`. And since `co` is also the relation you select from it wouldn't make much sense to exclude all names in there. Please edit your question and elaborate on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `co` is defined as a table, but you're using it like a column with the `NOT IN` operator. I would expect something like `WHERE customer.Name NOT IN co.Name`.

Comment: That query attempt doesn't make much sense. What are you trying to do? Shiw us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

`IN()` or `NOT IN()` predicates must have a parenthesized list of values or subquery. You don't have any parens in your predicate.

Also even if you had parens, you can't compare a column to an alias like that. In the context of a WHERE clause, a column is a scalar, but an alias is a set of columns.

I guess you're looking for customers who have no orders. Here's two ways of getting that:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM customers AS c
WHERE c.Id NOT IN (SELECT CustomerId FROM orders);
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.Name
FROM customers AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders AS o ON c.Id=o.CustomerId
WHERE o.CustomerId IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want to get the names of customers who have not placed orders 
but instead of placing the joined query after the `NOT IN` operator you placed it after `FROM`. 
 
If this is the case, use this:

```
SELECT Name
FROM customers
WHERE Name NOT IN (
  SELECT c.Name
  FROM customers AS c
  INNER JOIN orders AS o
  ON c.Id=o.CustomerId
)
```